# Sum and length of lists of list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

List `a` has zero values which have non-zero values in list `b` at corresponding points:

```
a = [[0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1]]
b = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0]]
```

I need sum of each list in `b` and length of non-zero values of each list in `a`. I get sum of lists in list `b` with:

```
s = [sum(i) for i in b] # output: [1, 5, 1]
```

But how do I get length of non-zero values in each list of `a` (expected output: `l = [2, 1, 2]`) and add resultant values (`s/l`) to each non-zero value of `a`?

Expected output:

```
[[0, 2.5, 2.5], [7, 0, 0], [2.5, 0, 1.5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting non-zero values can be done with `sum()` too:

```
l = [sum(v != 0 for v in i) for i in a]
```

This uses a property of Python booleans: they are a subclass of `int` and have integer values `0` and `1` for `False` and `True` respectively. As a result, summing booleans gives you an integer result letting you count how many of the `v != 0` tests are true.

To calculate `s / l`, zip their results together with the nested lists in `a`, then use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to add the ratio to each non-zero value:

```
s = [sum(i) for i in b]
l = [sum(v != 0 for v in i) for i in a]
result = [[0 if not v else v + (float(sumb) / count) for v in i]
          for i, sumb, count in zip(a, s, l)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1]]
>>> b = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0]]
>>> s = [sum(i) for i in b]
>>> l = [sum(v != 0 for v in i) for i in a]
>>> l
[2, 1, 2]
>>> [[0 if not v else v + (float(sumb) / count) for v in i]
...  for i, sumb, count in zip(a, s, l)]
[[0, 2.5, 2.5], [7.0, 0, 0], [2.5, 0, 1.5]]
```

You could pre-calculate the `s / l` ratio first; this can shave of a few cycles if the nested lists in `a` are very large:

```
ratio_sl = [sum(ib, 0.0) / sum(v != 0 for v in ia)  for ia, ib in zip(a, b)]
result = [[0 if not v else v + r for v in i] for i, r in zip(a, ratio_sl)]
```

Resulting output:

```
>>> ratio_sl = [sum(ib, 0.0) / sum(v != 0 for v in ia)  for ia, ib in zip(a, b)]
>>> ratio_sl
[0.5, 5.0, 0.5]
>>> [[0 if not v else v + r for v in i] for i, r in zip(a, ratio_sl)]
[[0, 2.5, 2.5], [7.0, 0, 0], [2.5, 0, 1.5]]
```

Here I stared `sum()` with a floating point `0.0` to ensure that Python 2 doesn't use integer division when calculating the ratios.